# False proof: $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}^2$ for any ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, fake-proofs

Let $A$ be any ring (commutative with unity). We show (falsely) that $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a^2}$ for any ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq A$.

Let
$$
0 \longrightarrow \mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow 0
$$
be the standard exact sequence which embeds $\mathfrak{a} \hookrightarrow A$ and projects $A$ onto $A/\mathfrak{a}$. Tensoring with $A/\mathfrak{a}$, we obtain a sequence
$$
\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow A \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow 0
$$
Using the fact that $\mathfrak{a} \otimes A/\mathfrak{a} \cong \mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2$, $A \otimes A/\mathfrak{a} \cong A/\mathfrak{a}$, and $A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{a} \cong A/\mathfrak{a}$, we derive an exact sequence
$$
\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2 \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \longrightarrow 0
$$
Since $A/\mathfrak{a} \to A/\mathfrak{a}$ is an isomorphism (in particular, injective), we must have $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}^2$, which is absurd for arbitrary $A$ and $\mathfrak{a}$.

Where is the error in this proof? I have a feeling that I've missed something silly, but I can't seem to find the hole in the logic.

Comment: Wait, how is $A\otimes A/\mathfrak{a} \cong A$? E.g. $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{a}=n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: My mistake, I meant $A \otimes A/\mathfrak{a} \cong A/\mathfrak{a}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is that you conclude from the fact that $\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2 \to A/\mathfrak{a}$ is the zero map that $\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2=0$. This would only work if we know that $\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{a}^2 \to A/\mathfrak{a}$ is injective, but since the sequence is only right exact, this doesn't work.

Incidentally, what you have given is a perfectly fine proof for $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}^2$ IF we assume that $A/\mathfrak{a}$ is flat. This does happen, e.g. in von Neumann regular rings, where every module is flat. As the proof shows, it is true that every ideal in a von Neumann regular ring is idempotent.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. I ran into this problem when trying to prove something about absolutely flat rings, where tensoring preserves left-exactness, but I couldn't figure out where the flatness criterion was used.

Comment: @EmorySun note that absolutely flat is a synonym for von Neumann regular (I have only seen the term absolutely flat in Atiyah-Macdonald I think, so probably von Neumann regular is more standard)

Comment: I never knew that - thank you for telling me! Incidentally, I've only ever studied commutative algebra from Aityah-MacDonald, so your observations about the terminology make sense.